# Make menu to work with box-sizing: border-box

Tags: html, css

I have a menu where the label appears when the mouse is over the icon:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <span>One</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see an example which working fine in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gWB6O68x9UcfduWflzOq?p=preview) demo.

But if I use:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box 
}
```

It stops working. The problem is in my site CSS I am using `border-box`.

Is there a way to have CSS that with `border-box` results in the same menu?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

ul{ 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width:100%
}

a:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width:0;
}

a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.3.0" data-semver="4.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
              <span>One</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              <span>Two</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="content">
        This is the content</br>
        Span of icon should be over content when mouse is over
      </div>        
      
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to do it like this, see the comments inline.

```
a {
    white-space: nowrap; /*icon and text on the same line*/
    position: relative; /*menu stays on top of content area*/
}
a span {
    display: none;
}
a:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And see the updated full code snippet.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    background-color: #d0d0d0;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap; /*added*/
    position: relative; /*added*/
}
a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
a span {
    display: none;
}
a:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>One</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Two</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This is the content<br/>
        Span of icon should be over content when mouse is over
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your navigation a to have `box-sizing: content-box`, give it `z-index: 1` so it shows up on top, add `white-space: nowrap`, and remove the width on your `a:hover` and `a:hover span`. Here is a complete working solution:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navigation a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

ul{ 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  background-color: #d0d0d0;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  
}

a:hover span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.3.0" data-semver="4.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      
      <div class="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
              <span>One with a bunch more text</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              <span>Two and you can have as much text as you want</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="content" style="color: red;">
        This is the content</br>
        Span of icon should be over content when mouse is over
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make your content text red? I think it is over the menu items text.

Comment: @Miguel Edited to show that the content text actually shows up below the menu item text.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply this in `a` tag and everything will be fine. You can use border-box after this on all elements

```
a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width:100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

Comment: Not quite ... when I increase the text inside the spam it shows in many lines. Check the updated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gWB6O68x9UcfduWflzOq?p=preview

Comment: Yea, i didn't know that you want to put more text inside that span, sry

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the following should work:

```
* {
 box-sizing: inherit;
  }
```

Comment: It does not solve everything. The text on the second item becomes in two lines ... I would like to show only in one line

Comment: Try removing the the width in this CSS element: `a:hover span`

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this and still keep the `box-sizing: border-box;` on all elements.

[See this Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/bbGR3r29DhKHS9LoVdix?p=preview)

Remove the `width` on `a:hover` and `a:hover span`.  Add `white-space: nowrap;` and `position: relative;` to `a`.

Comment: It is almost working but the text of the menu items appear under the content text. Why? Check it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/fYEeyHHyDRwBqXGnwUFh?p=preview ...

Comment: I've updated the answer to include one additional property (`position: relative;`) to ensure that the anchor (`a`) is overtop the content. @miguel